# How to send SIP messages with custom header using pjsua2 android

Tags: android, pjsip

With reference of that [enter link description here](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/structpj_1_1SendInstantMessageParam.htm)

I have send message successfully but I want to send custom header as well because of get status which particular message has send to update user

```
public void sendInstantMessage(String number, String msgBody) {
String sipServer = "aaa.ggg.net";
String buddy_uri = "<sip:" + number + "@" + sipServer + ">";

BuddyConfig bCfg = new BuddyConfig();
bCfg.setUri(buddy_uri);
bCfg.setSubscribe(false);

MyBuddy myBuddy = new MyBuddy(bCfg);
SendInstantMessageParam prm = new SendInstantMessageParam();
prm.setContent(msgBody);
```

// prm.setUserData(value)

```
try {
    myBuddy.create(account, bCfg);
    myBuddy.sendInstantMessage(prm);
    myBuddy.delete();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

}

By using `Token pj::SendInstantMessageParam::userData for link [enter link description here](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/structpj_1_1SendInstantMessageParam.htm)

I want to send the userdata header, but how to sent that header??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the solution for sending SMS with custom header using pjsip-2.4

Here is the code

```
String msgBody = "sending message";
    SendInstantMessageParam prm = new SendInstantMessageParam();
 prm.setContent(msgBody);
 SipHeader hName = new SipHeader();
 hName.setHName("name");
 hName.setHValue(uniqueId);

 SipHeaderVector headerVector = new SipHeaderVector();
 headerVector.add(hName);
 SipTxOption option = new SipTxOption();
 option.setHeaders(headerVector);
 prm.setTxOption(option);
 try {

  myBuddy.sendInstantMessage(prm);
 } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```